# Enum co-variance/polymorphism?

Tags: c++, enums

Imagine I have an enum defining a common option like:

```
enum valueState
{
   uninitialized,
   min,
   max
}
```

Now imagine I have a more specific value state for specific value types, lets say:

```
enum floatValueState
{
   nan
}
```

Would there be any way to pass the valueState options as floatValueStates ? Or is there some other way to achieve this kind of abstraction of choices at compile time without too much template noise.

EDIT:
Ofc they can implicitly convert to the type of enum, but how would you combine the two enums without overlapping values (like 0 = uninitialized, 4 = non) without specifying how many enums I will combine.

Comment: non-enum class have implicit conversion to `int`.

Comment: imagine a function `void foo(floatValueState state) { ... }` because of what @Jarod42 just mentioned, you could pass a `valueState` in fairly easily. You would have to keep track of the enumeration itself though if you want finer control. Overall, it's possible, but it's a poor design choice.

Answer (score 3):

Because old style `enums` (non-class) are just integers (implicit conversion), you can pass them around with disregard to which you're actually using. This is dangerous, but allows you to do what you want easily. You would need to micro-manage the values though, to make sure `nan` and `uninitialized` are not the same thing:

```
enum floatValueState {
   nan = 3
}
```

Anything accepting a `floatValueState` will implicitly accept a `ValueState`, with no extra work - what you want, but again, dangerous. Specifically, anything accepting a `ValueState` will also accept a `floatValueState` - and that could break stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is technically possible to solve this (see the other answer) - there is some theoretical problem: this is probably a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). That principle guides us how to use inheritance in sound OO design.

And it states: each "usage" of the "base type" - you can insert the "derived type" there.

Given that context - how would you "embed" that "additional information *nan*" here?

In other words (pseudo code):

```
 valueState value = ...
 if (value == min || max) {
 ... } else {
   value must be uninitialized
```

But what if `value` would now be floatValueState?!

Comment: Ah like that, interesting, seems like this problem is there anyway if we can just pass in any int though.